# Floor Functions Proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

I have a floor function proof that I need to do. The arithmetic of the actual problem isn't my problem. It is the way to do the direct proof. I don't know how to prove this. Prove that if x is a real number, then ⌊2x⌋ = ⌊x⌋ + ⌊x + 1/2⌋. 
I already know for any x this is true but how do you do the proof?

Comment: Can always do it in case.  Let x = [x]+ {x} were 0<= {x}  < 1.  If {x} < 1/2 then 2[x] <= 2x = 2[x]  + 2{x} < 2[x] + 1 so [2x] =2[x] and [x] < x + 1/2 = [x] + {x} + 12 < [x]+1 so [x+1/2] = [x] so [x]+[x+1/2] = 2[x]=[2x].  And if {x} > 12.  then 2x = 2[x] + 2{x} \ge 2[x]+1 (but clearly 2x = 2[x]+2{x} < 2[x] + 2) so [2x] = 2[x] + 1.  And x + 1/2 = [x] + {x} + 1/2 \ge [x] + 1 (but again clearly  x + 12 =[x]+{x} + 1/2 < [x] + 2) so [x + 1/2] = [x]+1